# Oil Tank Replacement

Tags: heating, leak, oil

I have been with Burke for the last 5 years.  My oil tank recently started to leak (indoors).
Fortunately, I caught it in time, so no spill.

I called Burke, and their response was excellent. However, they did charge me $1900 for the temporary tank install.
It will also cost $300 per month after 30 days.  They will refund me $400 if I let them do the rest of the job.  Has anyone else gone through this process, and has anyone had them remove and install a new oil tank? Any advice would be appreciated! Thank you all in advance.

Comment: It seems odd if buying a new tank, just remove old and place new.  Why need a temporary tank.  Or change fuel/heating system.

Comment: Presumably you agreed to whatever you agreed to to get the job done. In my local area a 275 gallon tank is a stock item costing ~$1000-1400, plus installation. I also can't see why a competent supplier would not just sell and install a new tank and transfer the oil from the leaking tank, but I don't know what you agreed to have them do. Presumably you'll want to complete the job in 30 days if you have a "temporary" rental unit costing 1/3-1/4 the price of a new tank every month.

Comment: I guess they might have brought out a temporary tank on the emergency call so they could eventually put the new tank in the same spot the leaking tank is in, and not put in the new tank right then as it would have been at "emergency rates" typically 1.5-2X higher than normal scheduled work rates. But I would have expected a discussion of the complete job and costs at that time, including the need for a second vist.